# Finding bijections between function and set of natural numbers

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Questions: Define a function g where it takes any function f with domain of size m and codomain of size n, and returns a natural number between 1 to $n^m$. Define the inverse of g.

Define a function g where it takes any bijection f with domain and codomain of size n, and return a natural number between 1 and n!
Define the inverse of g.

My thoughts: I have considered using prime factorisation, where the base is the nth item in the domain and the power is the mth item in the codomain. I have also tried multiplication where the position in the chain of multiplication is the nth item in the domain and value is the mth item in the codomain. (but it is commutative so I can't yield the inverse)

Comment: Why not start with small $n,m$?  See if you can get a good organizational principle.

Comment: For the first, consider the number written in base $n$.  For the second, I'm sure there is a duplicate here somewhere... but here is a programming stackoverflow post that you could get ideas from.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others

Comment: Thank you. For the 1st (for the reference of other people): order the elements in both domain and codomain. For the function f that matches mth element of domain to nth element of codomain, then in the mth position of the m-tuple, note down the value n. Repeat for the remaining. Treat this m-tuple as a base n number with m digits. Convert this into base 10.